# TextControl picture/text/different fonts

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I have a problem with formatting:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(" ", radTextBox_To.Text, 
    radTextBox_Subject.Text, textControl.Text);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
client.Port = 25;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("login", "password");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(mail);
MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

The mail message is delivered as a regular text message (no pictures) although `textControl.Text` contains a picture, text, different fonts. When the message is received, it comes across as standard text.

Comment: Are the fonts are also not showing, i mean is the text is also not formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `MailMessage.Body` property would render as plain text. You can change it to HTML by adding the following line of code after your declaration and prior to sending:

```cs
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Reference: [MailMessage.IsBodyHtml Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx)

Comment: received a message in plain text

Comment: Does the HTML render as plain text (i.e. you see tags)? Does the message even contain any HTML? I've used this code today and worked fine for me.

Comment: I'm sending a message to the mail.

textControl.Text - Text with different font and image.

But there comes a plain text.

Comment: I suspect something else is happening, such as calling textControl.Text isn't including the HTML. Try sending some hard-coded HTML (try `<strong>Hello</strong> <em>World</em>`) as a test to ensure that it's not MailMessage.

Comment: Just as I thought, well at least we know MailMessage is doing what it's supposed to. It seems that `textControl.Text` is returning the text with the HTML stripped. Assuming that it's not the native .Net textbox, does it have any other properties other than `.Text` that may include the HTML?